# Is there a way to prevent the taskbar icon from being hidden when hide is called on the parent window?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a parent and child window. When you push the button from the parent class the child is shown and the parent is hidden. Is there anyway to keep the taskbar icon visible when doing this?

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDateTime
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class ParentWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ParentWindow, self).__init__()
        self.cw = None
        self.button = QPushButton('Go to child')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.child)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()

    def child(self):
        self.cw = ChildWindow(self)
        self.hide()

    def parent(self):
        self.cw.close()
        self.show()

class ChildWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ChildWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QPushButton('Go to parent')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.parent().parent)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ParentWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a child QDialog "shares" the same taskbar entry as its parent, and when the parent is hidden, so does the taskbar entry, no matter if a child is visible.

A possible solution is to not hide the parent, but minimize it. Keep in mind that this has only been tested as working on Windows, on Linux you can have unexpected behavior (depending on how the window manager relates to modal windows) and I don't know how it will work out on MacOs.

The idea is to use [showMinimized()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMinimized) on the parent, then show the child, [activate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow) it to make it visible on top and, most importantly, use `exec_()` to ensure it has full control and make it behave as a dialog should.
Then we connect both the accepted and rejected signals of the dialog to restore the main window, and connect the clicked signal to accept.

```
class ParentWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ParentWindow, self).__init__()
        self.cw = None
        self.button = QPushButton('Go to child')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.child)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()

    def child(self):
        self.cw = ChildWindow(self)
        self.showMinimized()
        self.cw.show()
        self.cw.activateWindow()
        self.cw.exec_()

class ChildWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ChildWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QPushButton('Go to parent')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.accepted.connect(self.parent().showNormal)
        self.rejected.connect(self.parent().showNormal)
```

PS: I ended up not using a custom function to call back the parent at all, but remember that you shouldn't overwrite function/property names like `parent`.

Comment: @EvanBrittain you could also just use stackable widgets and have the menu bar belong to that which contains these stackable windows -- much simpler and cleaner